# JQuery - How can i apply jNice style on asp DropDownListBox, but not to other ListBoxes in the same form

Tags: asp.net, jquery-ui

How can i apply a jNice style on asp DropDownListBox, but not to selects in the same form. When I tryg to apply jNice style on listbox (ASP.NET), it is converted to dropdownlistbox. but I want it as a listbox in html code.

JQuery plugin 1.0 (11.26.08)

Thank You...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to find a way to uniquely identify them - for example if you apply an id convention that all `asp:DropDownListBox`s will have an id that starts with `asp` then you could write the following javascript:

```
$('select[id^="asp"]').addClass('jNice');
```

Comment: Thank You..for advice...what should I want is revert this selection (means apply to all elements, which are not contain "asp" in id...then what should i have to do